# How to iterate through nested array in C#?

Tags: c#, json, google-sheets-api

I have a console C# app and I use Google Sheets API to get data from spreadsheet. API returns me the following:

```json
{
    "majorDimension": "ROWS",
    "range": "Sheet1!A2:H1000",
    "values": [
        [
            "Test1",
            "20/07/2023",
            "21/07/2023"
        ],
        [
            "Test2",
            "10/08/2023",
            "12/08/2023"
        ]
    ],
    "ETag": null
}
```

These "values" are actually the values from the cells, and I need to loop through those values to extract the values "Test" and "Test2". Does anyone know how to do this?

```cs
var sheetRequest = sheetService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, "A2:H");

var sheetResponse = await sheetRequest.ExecuteAsync();

for (int i = 0; i < sheetResponse.Values.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sheetResponse.Values.Count; j++)
    {
        string s = (string)sheetResponse.Values[i][j];
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

I tried this. I don't know how to access elements? What is wrong?

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < sheetResponse[i].Count; j++)` or similar

Comment: `j` is supposed to read `Count` from `sheetResponse.Values[i]` I think.

Comment: Last column is empty, and when I want to access sheetResponse.Values[i][3], it says me "Index is out of range". I need that last column, regardless of the fact that it is empty. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

please try this.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

// Your JSON string
string jsonString = " 
{\"majorDimension\":\"ROWS\",\"range\":\"Sheet1!A2:H1000\",\"values\":[[\"Test1\",\"20/07/2023\",\"21/07/2023\"],[\"Test2\",\"10/08/2023\",\"12/08/2023\"]],\"ETag\":null}";

// Parse the JSON string into a JObject
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

// Access the "values" array
JArray valuesArray = (JArray)jsonObject["values"];

// Iterate over the "values" array
foreach (JArray innerArray in valuesArray)
{
    foreach (JToken token in innerArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(token.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As @orhtej2 has pointed out, you are missing a [i].  The code should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < sheetResponse.values.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sheetResponse.values[i].Count; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sheetResponse.values[i][j]);
    }
}
```

I am voting to close this as a typo.